# Expecting End of Statement

Tags: excel, vba, variables, excel-formula

Hey guys I keep on getting a `Compile Error: Expected:End of Statement` I inserted a variable into my formula so this table can be used over and over again based off of different sheet names.

could you guys please let me know what i am missing?
This Formula I am trying to insert is giving me the syntax error.

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=INDEX(PrevSh & [LENGTH],MATCH([MATERIAL], PrevSh & [MATERIAL],0)) & "(" & COUNTIF(PrevSh & [LENGTH],INDEX(PrevSh & [LENGTH],MATCH([MATERIAL],PrevSh & [Material],0)) )&")"

Dim PrevSh As String
PrevSh = ActiveSheet.Previous.Name

Range(TableName & "[QTY OF LNG]").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=INDEX(PrevSh & [LENGTH],MATCH([MATERIAL], PrevSh & [MATERIAL],0)) & "(" & COUNTIF(PrevSh & [LENGTH],INDEX(PrevSh & [LENGTH],MATCH([MATERIAL],PrevSh & [Material],0)) )&")"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula needs to be more like:

```
PrevSh = "OldTableName"
ActiveCell.Formula = "=INDEX(" & PrevSh & "[LENGTH],MATCH([@MATERIAL]," & PrevSh & "[MATERIAL],0)) & ""("" & COUNTIF(" & PrevSh & "[LENGTH],INDEX(" & PrevSh & "[LENGTH],MATCH([@MATERIAL]," & PrevSh & "[Material],0)))&"")"""
```

It is important to use your old table name off the previous sheet, rather than the sheet name.

Answer (score 2):

This is incorrect:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=INDEX(PrevSh & [LENGTH],MATCH([MATERIAL], PrevSh & [MATERIAL],0)) & "(" & COUNTIF(PrevSh & [LENGTH],INDEX(PrevSh & [LENGTH],MATCH([MATERIAL],PrevSh & [Material],0)) )&")"
```

It's parsing this as a string: `"=INDEX(PrevSh & [LENGTH],MATCH([MATERIAL], PrevSh & [MATERIAL],0)) & "`, then it hits a parenthesis and doesn't know what to do with it.  The same thing happens at the end with `)&")"`

**EDIT**: To clarify, the problem is less with your quotes, and more with the random parentheses.  You basically have this:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "Some nice text"("Some more text")"
```

This is not valid VBA.  I'm not 100% sure what you *want* the formula to be, but this won't do it.  I *think* you want something like this:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=INDEX(PrevSh & [LENGTH],MATCH([MATERIAL], PrevSh & [MATERIAL],0)) & ""("" & COUNTIF(PrevSh & [LENGTH],INDEX(PrevSh & [LENGTH],MATCH([MATERIAL],PrevSh & [Material],0)) )&"")"""
```

Notice the double quotes around the `(` and `)`, with a final closing quotation mark at the end.  If you are trying to have quotation marks in the formula in your cells, that's how you have to do it.

Comment: This formula is to be inserted when a certain sheet is created. When i get rid of the quotations on the outside of the formula it doesn't like that and automatically changes the MATCH and MATERIAL to just "Match" and "Material" and asks why these words aren't defined.

Comment: Then your quotes should be around those words; where they are, they are invalid syntax.

Comment: I must be missing something, when I add quotes around those words i get another Compile Error: Expected:End of Statement